# Efficiently reading .csv file containing tick-level fx data and converting it to OHLC data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I downloaded a number of .csv files containing FX data(tick-level) off dukascopy.com and I am keen to convert them into Pandas Series objects and then in turn resample them to OHLC. I have written the following function below (please also see data-set extract):

```
def extract_tickalt(file):
raw = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(file, index_col = 1, parse_dates=True)
ts = pd.Series(raw['Ask'])
return ts.resample('1min', how='ohlc')


# Data Sample 
Currency,timestamp,Bid,Ask
EUR/USD,20110102 21:50:01.700,1.33212,1.3374
EUR/USD,20110102 21:50:01.739,1.3345,1.3374
EUR/USD,20110102 21:50:01.901,1.33341,1.33611
EUR/USD,20110102 21:50:01.965,1.3345,1.33611
EUR/USD,20110102 21:50:56.741,1.3345,1.33502
...
```

The function works in itself but unfortunately it takes 15min per file. I had a look around for alternatives and I understand that there are some other modules with functions which could aid the process - however I am keen to use a solution native to pandas.

Comment: pandas read_csv actually claims to be pretty fast. see..http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=543. I can't be sure, but it might have something to do with parse_dates. You might want to use parse_dates = [2] instead of True

Comment: Well one thing I notice is that you are only using a single column, you can read just that column by passing it as a param in `read_csv`: `raw = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(file, index_col = 1, parse_dates=True, usecols=['Ask'])`

Comment: Thank you nitin and EdChum so far - still in the office - but will try as soon as I am home!

Comment: @EdChum I tried your suggested method and I hope I didn't get anything wrong but I end up getting the following error message 'list index out of range' ... any ideas?

Comment: That should've worked, can you edit your post with the first few lines from your csv, I tried on some dummy data here and it worked fine for me

Comment: OK I can reproduce your error, the problem arises because you specify the index col and this no longer appears in the columns to use as an index because you only specify a single column to use try this: `pd.read_csv(file, index_col=[0], parse_dates=True, usecols=['timestamp', 'Ask'])`

Comment: @EdChum thanks for this - this worked - your help has been much appreciated!